# Flex Builder not building changes

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flexbuilder

I'm having a very strange bug in Flex Builder where none of the changes I make are appearing when I debug/run my program. It only happens with a particular AS3 project, on others, it works fine.

For example, I have a line,`var x:int = this.prevX + this.x;`, whose value is 400 if I don't make any changes. I change the line to `var x:int = 0;` and set a breakpoint on the line. When I debug the program, it breakpoints just where it should, but the value is set to 400, even when the line is `x = 0`! What gives!

I've tried cleaning the project and deleting the project and re-importing it. No matter what I do, it won't show any changes I make, even if I just toggle a boolean. It still won't let me compile with errors, but once its done compiling, it completely ignore whatever changes I made. It's like it has the bytecode for the swf cached somewhere and its just ignoring doing the actual build step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have a copy of the swf in the html-template folder. The newly compiled swf will be overwritten by that old one after each build. Happened to me once.

Comment: Yes! I deleted the html-template folder and let it recreate and it works fine. You solved hours of struggle, thanks :)

Comment: Yep, it's 2012 and this is still an ongoing problem.  Thanks for the solution - it's obvious once you see that the .swf is clobbering the newly built one, but I never even thought to look there.

Comment: After struggling about an hour i found out that Chrome was caching the .sfw File. tried it with a different browser and it worked as intended. Clearing the cache solved the problem. Chrome version was 25.0.1364.99

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project in the Flex Navigator and then click Refresh. Refreshing the project worked for me.

Comment: Were you having the same exact problem or a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Changing from IE to Chrome worked for me.

Comment: So Chrome never has this issue or does it only work once in Chrome then you have to keep switching?

Comment: This is not an answer. Get some reputation so that you can leave comments instead. With real answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this as well, and deleting the html-template folder didn't fix the problem for me. I then renamed the project and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I get this too. 
This is the first time I've found this referenced on the net. It's a BIG problem. I get it periodically. For me, it's not the html-template folder. 
I've got a couple of ways around the problem at the moment

1. Delete the bin-debug swf
2. Overwrite it with a release build.
3. Delete the release swf
4. Export the release build elsewhere.
5. Build a debug version again.

This works - sometimes immediately sometimes after a few repetitions.

One other technique I tried today was to change the compiler options to -dump-config=somefile.
This worked immediately, however, I'll need to wait next time to try again. 
It might be a situation of changing the -dump-config filename output when this happens.

Just tried another possible fix (which seems to be working really well) - Change the browser that Flex builder is using to a different one. This immediately fixed the problem. I'll post back here later if I find that this is a reliable fix. - Casp